# В чем разница между listen port и listen ip:port в конфиге nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

Соединил два конфига nginx: в одном был `listen 1.2.3.4:443` в другом `listen 443`. Домены разные, оба работали на двух серверах. Соединил первый с `listen 1.2.3.4:443` в начале, с `listen 443` в конце конфига. Второй домен перестал работать. Присоединил второй домен include-ом поэтому не сразу заметил отличие с `listen 443`. Т.е. при добавлении ко второму домену IP (`listen 1.2.3.4:443`) заработало. Разъясните пожалуйста в чем была разница. Как я понимаю, нарушено было правило обработки и второй конфиг без IP просто не читался nginx-ом. Но где почитать о приоритете обработки, потому как порознь оба конфига работало без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listen 443` - nginx слушает 443-ый порт на всех интерфейсах

`listen 1.2.3.4:443` - nginx слушает 443 порт на интерфейсе с IP 1.2.3.4.

Про то, как вы "соединили" конфигурации - не очень понятно. Если можно, приведите сокращённый пример.

Прочитать про приоритеты можно [тут](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#name_based_https_servers) или [тут](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Точно, спасибо. Это называется читал, но не дочитал. "SSL-соединение устанавливается до того, как браузер посылает HTTP-запрос, и nginx не знает имени запрашиваемого сервера. Следовательно, он лишь может предложить сертификат сервера по умолчанию." У меня был второй домен, как listen 443 без ИП-адреса, поэтому браузер получал сертификат сервера по умолчанию от первого домена, как и написано в Вашей ссылке. Еще раз спасибо, что тыкнули носом в нужное место )))

Comment: Для тех, кто попадет сюда через поиск. Если дочитать ниже, то здесь https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni пишется, что должно работать и без указания IP. Нужно проверить "TLS SNI support enabled" для версии nginx. Тогда должно работать с 0.0.0.0 вместо указания IP интерфейса